# can be the troubble in GAS withSuccessHandler dots in response?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a problem with response from server (I think).

```
 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(theFunc).findInRow(query, sheetName);

function tehFunc(e) { 
    console.log('here');
    var val;
    $.each(e, function(i, item) {
      val = val+item.el1 + ' - ' + item.el2;
     })
  }
```

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: a is not a function

console is just not displayed;

Server side:

The findInRow function returns the data in the Logger.log as below

```
Logger.log([[{el1=3.0, el2=0.79}], []])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code example has miss spellings of `theFunc` vs `tehFunc`.  `theFunc` is not a declared function in your example.